# What does "for perspective" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Rachel Whalen remembers feeling gutted in high school when a former friend would mock her online postings, threaten to unfollow or unfriend her on social media and post inside jokes about her to others online.
>
> The cyberbullying was so distressing that Whalen said she contemplated suicide. Once she got help, she decided to limit her time on social media. It helps to take a break from it **for perspective**, said Whalen, now a 19-year-old college student in Utah.

I looked it up online, but couldn't find the meaning of it and only found "in perspective" or "for better perspective" etc.

What does the phrase mean here in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something "for perspective" means "[to put it in perspective](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+into+perspective)"--to correctly assess the size or importance of a thing relative to other events or objects.

So in this case, by taking a break from social media, Whalen gets enough perspective to see that even if the things that happen online are negative, they are not something to commit suicide over.